# Quitar tildes al tomar un comando por voz

Tags: python-3.x

en este momento estoy trabajando en un proyecto de clase que trata sobre crear un asistente virtual montado en Python 3.9 y que tome comandos ingresados por voz por parte del usuario y realice ciertas acciones definidas por el programador, la cuestión es que el programa toma las palabras que dice el usuario, pero con tildes y esto interfiere con el funcionamiento del programa, ya que al tomar estas frases y compararlas con los parámetros que yo como programador le he establecido, no encuentra ninguna similitud porque los parámetros los establezco sin ninguna tilde.
Comparto mi código para que se entienda un poco mejor:

`````
import wolframalpha
import pyttsx3
import tkinter
import json
import random
import operator
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import winshell
import pyjokes
import feedparser
import smtplib
import ctypes
import time
import requests
import shutil
from twilio.rest import Client
from clint.textui import progress
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import win32com.client as wincl
from urllib.request import urlopen
from unicodedata import normalize

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[2].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
 
def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
        speak("Buenos dias ")
  
    elif hour>= 12 and hour<18:
        speak("Buenas tardes!")   

    else:
        speak("Buenas noches!")  
  
    speak("Soy tu asistente, Viernes")
  
def usrname():
    speak("Como debo llamarte")
    uname = takeCommand()
    speak("Bienvenivo")
    speak(uname)
    columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
      
    print("Bienvenido.", uname.center(columns))
        
    speak("Como puedo ayudarte?")
 
def takeCommand():
     
    r = sr.Recognizer()
     
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
         
        print("Escuchando...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
  
    try:
        print("Reconociendo...")    
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='es-CO')
        print(f"Has dicho: {query}\n")
  
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)    
        print("Unable to Recognize your voice.")  
        return "None"
     
    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
       
    clear()
    wishMe()
    usrname()
     
    while True:
         
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if 'abre google' in query:
            speak("Abriendo google como lo pediste\n")
            webbrowser.open("google.com")
            
        elif 'abre youtube' in query:
            speak("Abriendo youtube como lo pediste\n")
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
        
        elif 'abre twitter' in query:
            speak("Abriendo twitter como lo pediste\n")
            webbrowser.open("twitter.com")   

            client = wolframalpha.Client("API_ID")
            res = client.query(query)
             
            try:
                print (next(res.results).text)
                speak(next(res.results).text)
            except StopIteration:
                print ("No results")     ````
`````

Comment: Sería más fácil ayudarte si reduces la pregunta a como quitar las tildes de un string. Proporciona una muestra de los strings que recibes y de las salidas que deseas.

Comment: te recomiendo usar este paquete ofrece varias opciones para limpiar texto crudo https://github.com/fcoclavero/textpreprocess